# Selenium Python condition search

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

So for a personal project I need to make an automation script in python for auction online.

I will use a csv file to load information like the name of the sells or the number of the object.

So far I use selenium to go to the website https://www.interencheres-live.com/index.html

I managed to log in into it. But when I want to use my variable **nameofthesells** i don't know how to get the link for the online sells.

For exemple with the sells with **nameofthesells** = "BIJOUX", i need to get the href link.

```
            <div class="lien"><a href="catalogue-46b4a326030aa43e118518ed30109b36.html" class="button gris">Découvrir la vente</a></div>
            <div class="date">
                <span class="jour">jeu.</span>
                <span class="date">28</span>
                <span class="mois">févr.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                                <p><span class="heure">10:30 :</span> <span class="titre">BIJOUX</span></p>
                <p class="photos">
                    <span class="p"><img src="https://thumbor.img.prod-indb.io/NauENIH9KiBGRfCmJ7YPOGZXATI=/fit-in/150x113/2019/02/21/185946_900211053_e402f6529c7eb7741ee3ed081f28c5f5"></span>
                    <span class="p"><img src="https://thumbor.img.prod-indb.io/_ST_7ZtRjBGLLFnWireUlRyb4_4=/fit-in/150x113/2019/02/21/190014_860571967_b87751b972d6298deb4bbcc1feedace7"></span>
                    <span class="p"><img src="https://thumbor.img.prod-indb.io/JYBFWddUYBJ9Ca55DOo9cakXga0=/fit-in/150x113/2019/02/21/190012_861627656_505cab9095c3664accb616e460ebd223"></span>
                    <span class="p"><img src="https://thumbor.img.prod-indb.io/J7LU7jthm9f7lagRIlVgwWcf_OM=/fit-in/150x113/2019/02/21/185942_842944321_d7f5c7bc3795ccadc63738a102d315da"></span>
                    <span class="p"><img src="https://thumbor.img.prod-indb.io/xJdfHZQQpd_Uk95wsAkrIabNY0k=/fit-in/150x113/2019/02/21/190026_88912100_17df6a96258ba281ca51f18d7dc27824"></span>
                </p>
                <p><span class="cp">Crédit municipal de Paris</span><br><span class="adresse">Crédit municipal de Paris 55, rue des Francs-Bourgeois - 75004 PARIS</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
```

Comment: All the code is wrap in this class : <div class="vente auction-46b4a326030aa43e118518ed30109b36" data-key="46b4a326030aa43e118518ed30109b36">